# Term for asking crowd to cheer louder

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

Sports people, sometimes after making a really impressive play, make a motion with their arms spread out moving up and down, basically signalling at the crowd to cheer louder.

Is there a better word or phrase I can use to describe this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pump up** the crowd.

> An action where you put your two arms out to your side and curve your
>   arms and scoop your hands inwards as [you're] flapping your arms up
>   and down ([Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pump%20up%20the%20crowd)).

Click here for examples: https://giphy.com/explore/pump-up-the-crowd.

Link to [Joe Bolden Pumping Up the Crowd](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPGpGnVaWdE).

Link to M-W's definition of [pump up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pump%20up).

Possibly related to *pump up the volume* (meaning increase the volume).

Answer (score 3):

They are *egging them on* to yell louder. I cannot find the origin but that is one use of it. To get the crowd aroused the player is said to be *rousing* the crowd.

Comment: Not sure the definition  of egg on may be applied to the context described by the OP: ***egg on*** : to urge or encourage (someone) to do something that is usually foolish or dangerous. (M-W)

Comment: 'egging on' is more of a taunt or dare than encouragement.

Comment: @Elliot, egging could also mean asking only using words, right? I would like a phrase/ term that also incorporates the action.